# How to include AIC in table after margins postestimation results

Tags: stata

I have a GLM model, which I estimate in Stata. The coefficients of interest are the marginal effects, which I get with `margins` command.

However, the postestimation table does not include summary statistics like AIC, which I would like to have there.

I have tried this by writing an auxiliary program `getAIC`:

```
program getAIC
    estat ic
    matrix list r(S)
    matrix S = r(S)
    scalar aic = S[1,5]
end
```

The estimation would then proceed like this:

```
 qui glm y x, fa(bin) link(probit)
 getAIC
 qui margins, dydx(x) post
 estadd loc AIC aic
```

And the output command is:

```
 esttab using output.tex, s(aic, fmt(0))
```

However, I don't have AIC in the results table.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the scalar `aic` from your program `getAIC` and use it accordingly.

The following works for me:

```
program getAIC, rclass
    estat ic
    matrix list r(S)
    matrix S = r(S)
    scalar aic = S[1,5]
    return scalar aic = aic
end

sysuse auto, clear

glm foreign price, fa(bin) link(probit)

getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)

margins, dydx(price) post

estadd local AIC `AIC'

esttab using output, s(AIC) replace

type output.txt
----------------------------
                      (1)   

----------------------------
price          0.00000766   
                   (0.43)   
----------------------------
AIC                 93.89   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It works fine as it is. I added an extension to my original question for a more general case that is still somewhat troublesome.

Comment: @Antti please start a new follow-up question as threads tend to grow considerably with extra questions and they ought to be self-contained. Thanks.