# Include additional statistics in table after multiple commands

Tags: stata

This is a follow-up to my earlier question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046495/how-to-include-aic-in-table-after-margins-postestimation-results).

I need to have both linear regression and glm model margin estimates in a result table. To include additional statistics to margins results is cumbersome, but can be dealt with some tinkering, in this case a program that I have names `getAIC`.

Unfortunately that tinkering omits the linear model statistics from the table.

This is what I've done:

```
program getAIC, rclass
    estat ic
    matrix list r(S)
    matrix S = r(S)
    ret scalar aic = S[1,5]
end

sysuse auto, clear

eststo m1: reg foreign price
*getAIC
*local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
*estadd local AIC `AIC'

glm foreign price, fa(bin) link(probit)
getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
eststo m2: margins, dydx(price) post
estadd local AIC `AIC'

esttab m1 m2 using output, s(AIC) replace

type output.txt

--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                  foreign                   
--------------------------------------------
price          0.00000760      0.00000766   
                   (0.41)          (0.43)   

_cons               0.250*                  
                   (2.00)                   
--------------------------------------------
AIC                                 93.89   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

If I comment back what I have commented out below the reg command, I will get what I need. But this is getting very messy, since I have several models and I need to get some more statistics than just AIC. I wonder if there is any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Hmm i just noticed you did that already (i worked the answer yesterday when you edited your previous post). Anyway, what do you mean more 'efficiently'? Can you tell us all the statistics that you need?

Comment: You are right, it works now. I was just wondering whether you could construct that program so that it does not interfere with linear model results. This way there will be lots of repetition in the code, which I'd like to avoid. DRY coding, rather than WET.

Comment: If you tell me which statistics you need i will try to work something out. Keep in mind that a lot depends on how `esttab` has been coded by its author.

Comment: And it is straightforward to have more statistics, i.e. `ll` and `BIC` in the program but each counts for more lines of code. Perhaps this is just nit-picking after all.

Comment: You will need to add more lines of code anyway. You cannot expect `esttab` to know on its own which statistics you want from each model.

Comment: Fair enough. It works, so that's all well. Thanks!

Comment: See my revised answer. You could also use a loop to automate the process of feeding certain arguments in your program depending on the model preceding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use your program `getAIC` twice:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo m1: reg foreign price
getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
estadd local AIC `AIC'

glm foreign price, fa(bin) link(probit)
getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
eststo m2: margins, dydx(price) post
estadd local AIC `AIC'

esttab m1 m2 using output, s(AIC) replace

type output.txt
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                  foreign                   
--------------------------------------------
price          0.00000760      0.00000766   
                   (0.41)          (0.43)   

_cons               0.250*                  
                   (2.00)                   
--------------------------------------------
AIC                 97.95           93.89   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

---

**EDIT:**

It really all depends on ***which*** statistics you need. For statistics directly provided in `r()` or `e()` you just need to specify the relevant local macros and add them using `estadd`.

For example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo m1: reg foreign price
getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
local LL = round(`e(ll)', .01)
estadd local AIC `AIC'
estadd local LL `LL'

glm foreign price, fa(bin) link(probit)
getAIC
local AIC = round(`r(aic)', .01)
eststo m2: margins, dydx(price) post
estadd local AIC `AIC'

esttab m1 m2 using output, s(AIC LL) replace

type output.txt

--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                  foreign                   
--------------------------------------------
price          0.00000760      0.00000766   
                   (0.41)          (0.43)   

_cons               0.250*                  
                   (2.00)                   
--------------------------------------------
AIC                 97.95           93.89   
LL                 -46.98                   
--------------------------------------------
```

For anything more 'exotic' such as AIC and BIC you will need to modify your program `getAIC` to extract these from other commands such as `estat`.

Comment: Thanks! I added revised program that has `ll` included too.

Comment: You do not need to add this in your program in this case. This is already returned in `e()` after `regress`. You are essentially repeating this step after `estat`.